# System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression.... 'could not be translated. ASP.NET 6 ...Translation of method 'DecodeFrom64' failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API Project, I'm trying to retrieve and decode the password from the database before comparing it with the entered password.

I have this code:

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(string email, string password)
{
     return await _context.Set<User>().Where(e => e.Email == email
                    && DecodeFrom64(e.Password) == password).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

I got this error:

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()
>     .Where(u => u.Email == __email_0 && 
> DbHelper.DecodeFrom64(u.Password) == __password_1)'
> could not be translated. Additional information: 
> Translation of method 'UserOnboardingApi.Model.DbHelper.DecodeFrom64' > failed.
> ```

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Expected to retrieve and decode the password from the database and compare to what the user entered

Comment: EF translates LINQ queries to SQL. It can't convert local function calls. Besides, passwords are meant to be salted and hashed *multiple* times with a strong cryptographic function made for this. ASP.NET Identity hashes passwords 10K times although the current guidance is to use 300K iterations

Comment: What is `DecodeFrom64`?  The error is telling you that it can't be translated into the target query language (likely T-SQL in this case).

Comment: Just add `.ToList()`: `return await _context.Set<User>().ToList().Where(e => e.Email == email && DecodeFrom64(e.Password) == password).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy: Sprinkling `.ToList()` everywhere as a magic solution will cause other problems.  Always materializing *the entire database table* into code for any query won't scale well.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy this is a serious problem, not a `just add ToList()`. In the best case this would only cover up the bad query problem and result in bad performance. In this case it's a data breach waiting to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF translates LINQ (when working with [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-7.0)) into SQL and it does not know anything about your method `DecodeFrom64` and can't translate it. Options are

- Encoding password and checking it server-side (db side):

```cs
public async Task<User> GetUser(string email, string password)
{
     return await _context.Set<User>()
          .Where(e => e.Email == email
                    && e.Password == YourEncodeMethod(password))
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

- Fetching the user by email (I suppose it should be unique) and check password client-side. Something along this lines:

```cs
public async Task<User> GetUser(string email, string password)
{
     var user = await context.Set<User>()
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Email == email);
     if(user is not null && DecodeFrom64(user.Password) == password)
     {
          return user;
     }
     return null;
}
```

- Implementing the decode function on the db side and [mapping it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping).

But in general you should consider storing password hashes ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/2501279)), not the encoded ones and check them.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your contributions....really leaned a lot.
@guru-stron your solved my issue thanks very much